# Passing PHP arguments into NetBeans into a page that features symfony url-routing

Tags: php, netbeans, symfony1, url-routing, xdebug

I am doing the Jobeet tutorial that features url routing.  The url routing (I think that's the proper term) makes urls look like this

http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/job/extreme-sensio/paris-france/2/web-designer

I would like to debug into this page however I cannot properly pass arguments into NetBeans.  I set the arguments in NetBeans "Run Configuration" area to this

job/extreme-sensio/paris-france/2/web-designer

however the url that is executed is this (notice the ? that NetBeans automatically appends to index file) 
http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php?job/extreme-sensio/paris-france/2/web-designer

Because of the ? it doesn't work properly.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hy
look again under the Project Properties to obtain, since you can specify at run Command Line argument.