# Debug a action method with XDebug, bypassing the login form on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug, eclipse-pdt, sonata-user-bundle

I'm debugging a Symfony 2.3 application with Sonata User and Sonata Admin bundles (with XDebug over Eclipse Kepler PDT) and I need to debug one specific form, but I want to bypass the login form and all the debug involved, because the process is too way long.

Comment: can you use an in_memory login http-auth based and create a simple client with auth params?

Comment: If you mean to this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html, I tried, but I couldn't understand the approach. Where do I have to put that sample code?

Comment: Someone suggest me to use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836229/how-to-debug-symfony-in-netbeans-i-cannot-call-specific-pages

In my case will be Eclipse PDT, instead NetBeans.